# SQL Server - Which one is optimum, page split or low selectivity

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to obfuscate a non-clustered index column, but some of the values of this column are very short and my generic obfuscation logic might result in duplicate column value (I am preserving the length while obfuscating). Though I will not use this value for any selection (this value is almost like deleted), since this is part of an index, having duplicate will reduce the selectivity. Other approach would be, if the value is smaller, generate a GUID as a replacement text, but the problem with this approach would be, if the data page is already full, it may result in page split.

Considering my objective is to junk the value, what is the best and optimized approach in this case?

Comment: If you are not using the value for selecting, why is it in the index?

Comment: Per Gordon's remark, if you make all obfuscated values use a unique character not used in "real" values, you can apply a [filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes) to your index to exclude them entirely. Even better would be to use a column for the deleted state and use that in your index filter(s).

Comment: Column values are in use for selection, but once the value is obfuscated, no one will send those values as parameter to run select statement. Basically this obfuscation is being done in order to meet some data compliance. So values which meet compliance rule over a period need to be obfuscated. We cannot delete or filter those rows as this could effect the reporting, numbers will go wrong.

Comment: A *filtered index* does not remove or eliminate any rows from the base table and will yield the same results for queries that do counting. Correct results are never dependent on how you index; only performance is.